# X13 Arima with negative values

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm running x13 Arima analysis on a US GDP series to get the "trend" component.

```
2008-12-31  -8.2
2009-03-31  -5.4
2009-06-30  -0.5
2009-09-30  1.3
2009-12-31  3.9
2010-03-31  1.7
2010-06-30  3.9
2010-09-30  2.7
2010-12-31  2.5
2011-03-31  -1.5
2011-06-30  2.9
2011-09-30  0.8
```

As you can see the data has negative values and when trying to run the model on the data it complains:

> X13Error: WARNING: Automatic transformation selection cannot be done
>   on a series with zero or negative values.

What is the right way to run X13 when you have negative values in your series?

(This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000059/statsmodels-x13error-warning-automatic-transformation-selection-cannot-be-do where I asked about the specific program settings. I asked this question first in Quantitative Finance beta, but was redirected to this community.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall US GDP going *negative* per se, so I assume you are working with growth rates, which can indeed go negative (and do so during recessions, pretty much by definition).

ARIMA as such *can* deal with negative values, so this would not be a problem for plain ARIMA. The problem is that [X13-ARIMA uses Box-Cox (and logistical) transformations](https://www.census.gov/ts/x13as/docX13AS.pdf), and these are simply not defined for negative values.

I have never heard of [X13-ARIMA](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/) being used for growth rates (or differenced series, which would have the same problem). In my experience, it is *always* used on the original macroeconomic series, and these *cannot* go negative. If ARMA dynamics are only present in rates of change of the original series, X13-ARIMA will happily difference your series for you.

Comment: thanks Stephan, they are indeed growth rates, but shouldn't this work if one is able to specify the model as "additive" instead of "mutliplicative" (Not that I know how to do that here).

Comment: The problem is not a multiplicative model - it's the [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform), as per your error message. Perhaps you can turn the automatic transformation off in the modeling software, which I'm not familiar with.